# calling and updating a php object variable (problem defining variables)

Tags: php, oop

I have an issue when I created a class in PHP. When I define two variables. PHP automatically updates both variables to be the same. Why is is that happening? the output that I want is the following:

Hello World: this is a new string 10

but I get:

Hello World: 1010

what is wrong with my code. The variables are defined, then I'm using the construct function to initialize the variables. In my code, when I update the variables both are updated at the same time. That should not happen with the last command.

I'm creating this in a self published webpage called index.php for testing purposes and to explain what is happening in my code. You will have to run a server with php capabilities in order to see my example. The code is the following:

```
<?php

class testClass {

public $public_str;
public $public_int;

function __construct() {
    $this->$public_str = "this is a string ";
    $this->$public_int = 0;
}

//string
function newVar($newText) {
  $this->$public_str = $newText;
}

function getPublicVar() {
  return $this->$public_str;
}

//var
function newInt($newInt){
  $this->$public_int = $newInt;
}

function getPublicInt(){
  return $this->$public_int;
}

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php


$object_test = new testClass;
$object_test->newVar("this is the new string ");
$object_test->newInt(10);


$output = '<p> hello World:  ' ;
$output .= $object_test->getPublicVar();
$output .= $object_test->getPublicInt();
$output .= '</p>';

//alternatively
$output .= '<p> hello World:  ' ;
$output .= $object_test->$public_str;
$output .= $object_test->$public_int;
$output .= '</p>';

echo $output;

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When accessing properties of a class, you should not use the variable-identifier `$` in front.

Comment: Great fast response. That solved my problem.! Thanks.

Comment: Just something about using classes - properties shouldn't normally be `public`, especially as you have methods to access them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yout syntax is wrong.

```
$this->$public_str = $newText;
```

Should be:

```
$this->public_str = $newText;
```

The same goes for the other variables.